# How to override the NHibernate identity Id name

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have the following class;

```
public class Country
{
    public virtual int CountryId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Code { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual bool Preferred { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime LastChanged { get; set; }
}
```

I've using Fluent NHibernate's automapping to associate my tables with my objects.

```
public static class SessionFactoryBuilder
{
    public static ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory()
    {
        return Fluently.Configure()                              
            .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(""))
            .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(CreateMappings()))
            .BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    // Returns our mappings
    private static AutoPersistenceModel CreateMappings()
    {
        return AutoMap
            .Assembly(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly())
            .Where(t => t.Namespace == "Escape.Data.Entities");
    }
}
```

How can I override the identity Id for the table from Id to CountryId which is defined in my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should use the convention here. To change the default Primary Key Name, we can use

```
PrimaryKey.Name.Is(x => x.EntityType.Name + "Id")
```

The Column name convention could be like this So let's implement `IIdConvention`:

```
public class MyIdColumnNameConvention : IIdConvention
{
    public void Apply(IIdentityInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Column(instance.EntityType.Name + "Id");
    }
}
```

And add it to configuration

```
return AutoMap
        .AssemblyOf<Country>(t => t.Namespace == "Escape.Data.Entities")
        // use the convention
        .Conventions.Add(PrimaryKey.Name.Is(x => x.EntityType.Name + "Id"))
        .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyIdColumnNameConvention >()
```

See more here:

- [Auto mapping](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Auto-mapping)
- [Conventions](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions)

Comment: I tried what you suggested but am getting the exception "The entity 'Country' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id"

Comment: I updated my answer. I was thinking about the Column, sorry, while we need to set the convention to the C# Name...

Comment: Am not sure what the problem is, but I'm getting the error of "The entity 'Country' doesn't have an Id mapped. Use the Id method to map your identity property. For example: Id(x => x.Id)."}"

Comment: Just to be sure, calling assembly is the one where the Country is? What about `AutoMap.AssemblyOf<Country>(type => t.Namespace == "Escape.Data.Entities")` to be sure.. I mean, https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Conventions this should help more... I do not see any issue above

Comment: @Tommo1977 do you know what? are you able to make it working with explicit mapping of the country? Just to be sure, that all these settings are really reading the up to date setting. I mean, that all .dll are rebuilt... and correctly found

Comment: I can make if work using Explicit mapping, if I change the CountryId in the database table to Id.

Comment: Well then it seems, that the Convention `MyIdColumnNameConvention` is not used... try to pass only this convention. It is so usuall scenario... we must be very close... I'd needed more info

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46759/discussion-between-tommo1977-and-radim-kohler)

Comment: I know this question is old, but why is it necessary to do both `.Conventions.Add(PrimaryKey.Name.Is(x => x.EntityType.Name + "Id"))` and `.Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyIdColumnNameConvention>()`? Thanks!

Comment: @Don01001100, in case I do understand your question correctly (if not issue new question and add link to this) ... both do different thing, but with the same result. First is inlined version profiting from being able to send just a statement, the second just makes it more OOP oriented (which is always easier to maintain and extend).. so both are NOT needed at time.. you are right